# How to extend multiple mixins in the same Polymer element?

Tags: javascript, class, polymer, javascript-objects, mixins

I am updating my Polymer App to 2.0, while trying to get familiar with the new concepts.

I would like to extend two mixins: `DatastoreBehaviors` and `FacebookBehaviors` in my Polymer element, but I can't figure out how to proceed:

element:

```
  class AppFeed extends DatastoreBehavior(Polymer.Element) {

      static get is() { return 'app-feed'; }

      ...


}
```

mixins 1:

```
const DatastoreBehaviors = (superClass) => class extends superClass {

    ...
}
```

mixins 2:

```
  const FacebookBehaviors = (superClass) => class extends superClass {

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just had a quick look at the docs, is [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins) what you are looking for?

Comment: @BenThomas thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple inheritance can be achieved in Polymer in following way

```
class AppFeed extends DatastoreBehavior(FacebookBehaviors(Polymer.Element)) { … }
```

which will create inheritance hierarchy like

```
AppFeed <= DatastoreBehavior(FacebookBehaviors(Polymer.Element)) <= 
FacebookBehaviors(Polymer.Element) <= Polymer.Element
```

You can also refer [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins).